# Crystal Report Query:- Basically i am trying to extract the data from description file which has both alphabets & numbers

Tags: crystal-reports

Please can anyone help me with below query as i am using crystal report 11 version.

unable to fetch data from string field which has numbers included like (FUSING -012172-60") and i am using this formula in parameter {ITEM.DESC} like {?Description(Article)} & '*'

And my parameter input will be numbers like (012172)

Comment: Use wildcards at both ends of the parameter.